# Where is the Milky Way located in the Futurama universe?

Tags: futurama

Based on available information such as:

- It was a short trip to one of the edges of the universe.
- Other flights required naptosis and weeks of travel.

And given the increased speed of light. About where is the Milky Way in the universe? What is the minimal size of the universe given the available data?

Comment: Why the not constructive vote. Defend! hehe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Planet Express Ship's engine is no ordinary engine.  It was made by **THE PROFESSOR**!  The engine is fueled by *Dark Matter* and was made to move the universe around it.

For all we know, the Planet Express Crew went to the edge of the universe in a week or so but the time frame was just **skipped** so the episode could continue.

The show **sometimes** skips travel time to get the plot started, some plots are within the travel time so they don't skip it.  This way the show can have a more opened show.
Its like cutting the boring scenes out.

As for the shape of the Universe, I don't think there was anything in Futurama saying that the universe changed.  So it would be likely that normal expansion of the universe has occurred.

Comment: Normally I would agree, but I believe it was a plot point that Fry and the gang were taking the "rest of the morning off" to do all the things Fry wanted to do: blow up a planet, see the edge of the universe, bang a celebrity. (episode was "I Dated a Robot") - This puts a clear time range on the flight, probably less than an hour.

Comment: They could've gone through a wormhole similar to the Panama Wormhole.  Or the 18 Wormhole hole in the giant miniature gold course.